# Firefox doesn't support H.264 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, firefox, youtube, h.264

Something is not right with my Firefox and Windows 7 combo because reportedly, it should work, but Youtube's test page says otherwise:

[image]

The problem I'm having is on certain videos Youtube gives me this cheeky message which [suggests](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6322658) to use other combinations of browsers and OSes:

[image]

I'm using Firefox Developer Edition 51 (latest to date) and I'm on Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit with no "N" suffix. Many mention the "N" as it means there are no media codecs installed, and I'd have to get a special ~300mb installation from Microsoft's site (it's free). I tried it and it says it's not applicable for my case.

There are also outdated suggestions to change some bool flags in about:config which are already enabled at this point.

I have K-lite codec pack installed with maximal options, and I don't have media player uninstalled or missing checkboxes in any media-related options in the Windows Features list (available through the uninstallation control panel).

What's missing?

Comment: It works in the release version. Have you checked for outstanding bugs in the developer version?

Comment: Doesn't work for me, in fact it's [missing one more item](http://i.stack.imgur.com/W9KfC.png). What Windows do you have?